# ReactJS - How to queue requests (fast button clicks), and handle responses consecutively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, queue, synchronous

The sub component below is supposed to display navigation buttons and render the appropriate result on button press (first, next, prev, last).  Unfortunately, due to the asynchronous nature of inputs (fast button presses), I can not capture all button presses to process in order.   I modified the sub component to be as simple as possible, but unfortunately it does not even respond to button presses, because I am not sure how to handle changes to the property, namely this.requests?

How do I make this work according to the intended behavior?

Sub Component

```
import React from 'react';

export class EditRiskNavigationButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            riskid : props.riskId
        }
        this.requests = []
    }
    queueRequest = (request) => {
        this.requests.push(request);
    }
    handleNextRequest = () => {
        if (this.requests.length) {
            return this.props.getRisk(this.requests.shift());
        }       
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="First" onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'first')} />
                <input type="button" value="Prev"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'prev')} />
                <input type="button" value="Next"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'next')} />
                <input type="button" value="Last"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'last')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Main Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-jss';
import { formatDateMDY } from '../../common/Functions';
import { EditRiskNavigationButtons } from './EditRiskNavigationButtons';
//import './EditRisk.jss';

class EditRisk extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.formatDateMDY = formatDateMDY.bind(this);
    this.getRisk = this.getRisk.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      risk: [],
      riskid: 0,
      riskAPIUriParams: '',
      message: ''
    };
  }
  getRisk = (gotoRisk = 'first') => {
    this.state.riskAPIUriParams = (this.state.riskid || "") + "/" + gotoRisk
    if (this.state.riskid != 0)
      this.state.riskAPIUriParams = "/" + this.state.riskAPIUriParams;
    return fetch("http://projectaim/api/risks"+this.state.riskAPIUriParams)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          risk: result.data,
          riskid: result.data.riskid,
          message: result.message
        });
      },
      // Note: it's important to handle errors here
      // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
      // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded)
      this.getRisk('first');
  }
  handleSubmit(event){
    
  }
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
         return (
          <div id="formcontainer">
            <div id="myeditform">   
              <form id="form" name="EditRisk" ng-submit="">
                <div class="layout"></div>
                  <EditRiskNavigationButtons getRisk={this.getRisk} />
                  {JSON.stringify(this.state.risk.riskid)}
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }
}
render(<EditRisk/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Do you *need* to process all clicks? Or would throttling/debouncing the callback be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I don't necessarily, but it is an exercise in understanding how to implement such functionality.

Comment: I don't think you need the request array in the child, and I see that you are mutating the state object in `getRisk` in the parent component. When you are mutating state and doing other unintentional side-effects it makes using React a little less determinant. If for each click in the child you called `getRisk` you eliminate the "queue". You could maybe track a timestamp for each request in the parent and if they requests resolve out of order then ignore those responses since you've already handled a later request.

Comment: I was think of recording all requests in a queue but I don't seem to grasp how to properly read from the queue if not empty, like in a loop.  Is that a viable approach.  My current queue is an attempt at this but not successful.  Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Right, this is likely because you are trying to use this queue *outside* the React component lifecycle. You would need to have additional code polling the queue on an interval for requests to process, batch/bulk process them, and update some React state with the results.

Comment: I've just started with React so I might be introducing some non conventional ways of approaching this.  I started off by considering disabling all buttons while in process, but then wanted to try to consider handling all requests, before which I noticed I was getting requests lost due to race conditions and the fact I had to wait for my logic to complete fetching data from the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear if this is a definitive solution, but I believe using async / await in a polling loop code captures all requests.   Any comments or revisions are appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';

export class EditRiskNavigationButtons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            riskid : props.riskId
        }
        this.requests = []
    }
    queueRequest = (request) => {
        this.requests.push(request);
    }
    processNextRequest = async () => {
        var nextRequest;
        if (this.requests.length) {
            nextRequest = this.requests.shift();
        }
        return this.props.getRisk(nextRequest);
    }
    pollForRequests = async () => {
        while (true) {
            await this.processNextRequest();
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       this.pollForRequests();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="First" onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'first')} />
                <input type="button" value="Prev"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'prev')} />
                <input type="button" value="Next"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'next')} />
                <input type="button" value="Last"  onClick={this.queueRequest.bind(this, 'last')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I also need to modify processNextRequest like below to return a promise that waits for this.requests[] to get at least one element on it to prevent unnecessary looping unless the user clicks one or more times on the navigation button.

```
 processNextRequest = async () => {
        var nextRequest;
        if (this.requests.length) {
            nextRequest = this.requests.shift();
            return this.props.getRisk(nextRequest);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => resolve(this.requests.length));
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Practically speaking, if I want this to be completely and correctly responsive, I should empty the queue on when a button change occurs, so that the requests don't keep going.